# How can i recover my deleted messages

Tags: samsung, sms, data-recovery, samsung-galaxy-s-9

Recover deleted SMS message using Google Backup?

I u Google auto backup service is turned on. Recently I deleted my SMS messages and now I want to recover one particular SMS. Is it possible via Google Backup? If yes, what is the correct way?

Comment: Are you certain Google did backup of your messages? Can you see SMS/messages in Google backup options? Normally, SMS apps disallow backups.

Comment: Note that Google Backup is also a sync solution, so even if SMS messages also get backed up, deleting them on the device will also delete the one inside the backup.